# How to implement Cartesian product helper class

Tags: c#, cartesian-product

I'm trying to implement a solution using Felice Pollano's Cartesian product helper class, found [here](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/08/12/HelperClassForTheCartesianProductOfMoreThanTwoArrays.aspx).

His example on calling his class uses literal string arrays, like:

```
var cross = new CartesianProduct<string>(
           new string[] { "JUICY", "SWEET" }
           , new string[] { "GREEN", "YELLOW" }
           , new string[] { "APPLE", "BANANA", "MANGO" });
```

This works as expected.

In my implementation I need to do something more dynamic, as I need to pull values from XML. I'm getting hung up on how to do this. For example, this does not work:

```
object[] array = new object[] {new string[] { "JUICY", "SWEET" } , 
new string[] { "GREEN", "YELLOW" }, 
new string[] { "APPLE", "BANANA", "MANGO" } };

var cross = new CartesianProduct<object>(array);
```

The constructor is taking the input array as a single `param`, which is fouling things up.

Any suggestions on how I can call this class differently to make it work or update the helper class to support what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor accepts a `string[][]`, not an `object[]` that has `string[]` as the objects.

It's just a minor change in how you construct the array though:

```
string[][] array = new string[][] 
{
    new string[] { "JUICY", "SWEET" }, 
    new string[] { "GREEN", "YELLOW" }, 
    new string[] { "APPLE", "BANANA", "MANGO" } 
};
```